# Python pygame character idle animation

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I have an update method for the player class that checks a list that I have stored the two image files for the idle animation. In my update method I'm checking if enough time has passed and I should update the image or not. It animates once initially running the script but stops, how do I make it continuous?

```
import pygame
import os
from os import path

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')

WIDTH = 720
HEIGHT = 360
FPS = 30

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, size):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = 500

    def update(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame == 1:
                center = self.rect.center 
                self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][self.frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center
                self.frame = 0
            if self.frame == 0:
                center = self.rect.center 
                self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][self.frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center
                
                
                


        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

playerIdle_anim = {}
playerIdle_anim['lg'] = []

for i in range(2):
    filename = 'player_idle0{}.png'.format(i)
    img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, filename)).convert()
    img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    img_lg = pygame.transform.scale(img, (128, 75))
    playerIdle_anim['lg'].append(img_lg)
    
        
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player('lg')
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #draw / render
    all_sprites.update()
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. you do not need to type in editor same operations in every case of frame index.
   I think you just need to calculate index of frame and draw it in Update() in one algorythm

Change cases:

```
   def update(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame == 1:
                center = self.rect.center 
                self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][self.frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center
                self.frame = 0
            if self.frame == 0:
                center = self.rect.center 
                self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][self.frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center
    ................
```

to calculation:

```
    def update(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now            
            self.frame = (self.frame + 1) % len(playerIdle_anim['lg'])
            center = self.rect.center 
            self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][self.frame]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = center
    ................
```

2. Also, may be you should set frames list (playerIdle_anim['lg']) inside class.

Instead of:

```
 class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self, size):
         pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
         self.size = size
```

write:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, FramesList):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.frames = FramesList        
        self.image = self.frames[0]
        ................
    def update(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now            
            self.frame = (self.frame + 1) % len(self.frames)
            center = self.rect.center
            self.image = self.frames[self.frame]
        ................

................
player = Player(playerIdle_anim['lg'])
................
```

*I hope you understand my English*

Answer (score 2):

@PSV offers good advice about your animation code layout, and the changes will fix and simply the code, but it does not explain what is wrong.

The reason your animation stops is because the calculation of the next-frame-index is not quite right.  It always stays on frame `0` right?

Let's mentally walk through your `update() function:

```
def update(self):
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
        self.last_update = now
        self.frame += 1                          # <<- UPDATE HERE
        if self.frame == 1:
            ...            
            self.frame = 0
        if self.frame == 0:                      # <<-- NOT an "else"
            ...
```

When the animation starts, `self.frame` is `0` (set in `__init__`).  Some time passes and `self.frame += 1` happens. Now we check if `self.frame == 1`, it is, so we set the image to `frame['lg'][1]`, and `self.frame` back to `0` again.  Some time passes, and `self.frame += 1` happens ...

The code is forever having `self.frame += 1` *before testing*, so it always goes down the path to set frame #1.  However, because there's two `if` statements (rather than an `if` and `else`) as soon as `self.frame` is set back to zero (as part of the index being `1`), the next clause `if self.frame == 0` is immediately allowed too, so you get two updates!  But the human never sees the first update, just the final result.

Removing the `self.frame += 1`; Adding a `self.frame = 1` and changing the second `if` to be an `else` will fix the code simply:

```
def update(self):
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
        self.last_update = now
        if self.frame == 1:
            center = self.rect.center 
            self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][self.frame]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = center
            self.frame = 0
        elif self.frame == 0:                      # <-- HERE
            center = self.rect.center 
            self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][self.frame]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = center
            self.frame = 1                         # <-- HERE
```

However this is rather dogey.  What about when your animation is 12 frames, you don't want to have 12 nearly identical clauses.  There's got to be a better way of handling the index updates.

The code @PSV answered with solves this "next image index" update problem by using the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (division remainder) of the frame-count compared with the current frame.  So if you have say 7 frame in the list, using this in the modulus returns 0 -> 6, stopping the index overflowing.  It's equivalent to something like:

```
self.frame += 1
frame_count = len( playerIdle_anim[self.size] )
if ( self.frame >=  frame_count ):
    self.frame = 0
```

This allows you to reduce you frame-picking code down to two sections:  updating the index, and setting the image:

```
now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
    # Update image index
    self.last_update = now
    self.frame += 1
    # ensure the frame-index loops around the list
    if ( self.frame >= len( playerIdle_anim[self.size] ) ):
        self.frame = 0
    # Change the frame to the next (or 0th) image
    center = self.rect.center 
    self.image = playerIdle_anim[self.size][self.frame]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = center
```

Comment: This works when I keypress up and down it doesn't animate, but when I travel left and right it continues the animation for some reason.

Comment: @BrandOcOder - The event handling for player input needs to be moved down into your main loop.  This will allow the update animation to run independently to movement.